# Getting an error "Expected function or variable" while calling a sub from another

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is my code. Debugger points second sub, where is the problem. I wish to save document as pdf with two different pre_word.

```
 Sub yeniDosyaAdiVer()
  yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri = Split(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")
  yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi = UBound(yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri)
  'MsgBox ("Kelime sayısı:" & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi)
    For xcv = 0 To (yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi - 1)
     'MsgBox (xcv & ". kelime:" & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri(xcv))
      sonDosyaAdi = sonDosyaAdi & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri(xcv) & "."
     'MsgBox (sonDosyaAdi)
    yeniDosyaAdiVer = sonDosyaAdi
End Sub

Sub TİTCK2pdf()
    With ActiveDocument
      .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="titck-imza-" & yeniDosyaAdiVer() & "pdf", _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
      OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
      Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
      CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
      BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    End With
End Sub

Sub TİTCK_ic2pdf()

With ActiveDocument
  .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="titck-imza-ic-" & yeniDosyaAdiVer() & "pdf", _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
  OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
  Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
  CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
  BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yeniDosyaAdiVer()` is a sub. it doesn't return nothing... in the second line of TITCK you want to insert the value so you need to change Sub to Function

```
Function yeniDosyaAdiVer()
  yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri = Split(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".")
  yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi = UBound(yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri)
  'MsgBox ("Kelime sayısı:" & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi)
    For xcv = 0 To (yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleriSayisi - 1)
     'MsgBox (xcv & ". kelime:" & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri(xcv))
      sonDosyaAdi = sonDosyaAdi & yeniDosyaAdiKelimeleri(xcv) & "."
     'MsgBox (sonDosyaAdi)
    yeniDosyaAdiVer = sonDosyaAdi
End Function

Sub TİTCK2pdf()
    With ActiveDocument
      .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="titck-imza-" & yeniDosyaAdiVer & "pdf", _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
      OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
      Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
      CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
      BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    End With
End Sub

Sub TİTCK_ic2pdf()

With ActiveDocument
  .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="titck-imza-ic-" & yeniDosyaAdiVer & "pdf", _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
  OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
  Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
  CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
  BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It works now but this time err message changes to not a valid file name. File names including "-" char. Is it reserved character?

Comment: i think you maybe missing a dot before pdf or may not need the .pdf at all since youre exporting as a pdf already. just play with it